# Searching for files inside a directory using NSMetadataQuery

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument

My app is using UIDocument + iCloud to create and view documents. The files are stored this way:

- Documents/Filename.db
- Documents/Filename.db/File.db (Filename.db is the directory)

Files inside the Documents/Filename.db directory loads fine at its own View Controller. When opening Documents/Filename.db/File.db inside another View Controller, I'm having problems loading those files. *The filenames are not fixed and there are multiple occurrences of them. I can verify that the files are stored inside the directory, so that shouldn't be the problem.*

I think I've tracked down the problem to NSMetadataQuery, because it's only searching inside Documents/ - **I want it to search inside the directory Documents/Filename.db**. I've tried setting the query serachScope to the correct path, but it seems like I need to use NSMetadataQueryUbiquityContainerDocumentsScope for searching to return results.

```
- (NSMetadataQuery *)documentQuery 
{
NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

NSString *appending = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.db/", currentDirectory]; // Directory name
NSURL *documentPath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:appending];
NSLog(@"Document Path: %@", documentPath);

if (query) {

    [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

    NSString *filePattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*.%@", STACK_EXTENSION];
    [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, filePattern]];

}

return query;

}

- (void)processiCloudFiles:(NSNotification *)notification
{
[_query disableUpdates];
[_iCloudURLs removeAllObjects];

NSArray *queryResults = [_query results];
for (NSMetadataItem *result in queryResults) {

    NSURL *fileURL = [result valueForAttribute:NSMetadataItemURLKey];

    NSLog(@"---- FileURL: %@", fileURL);

    NSNumber *aBool = nil;

    [fileURL getResourceValue:&aBool forKey:NSURLIsHiddenKey error:nil];
    if (aBool && ![aBool boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"Adding following Stack: %@", fileURL);
        [_iCloudURLs addObject:fileURL];

    }

}

NSLog(@"Found %d iCloud files", _iCloudURLs.count);
NSLog(@"iCloud URLs: %@", _iCloudURLs);

...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your directory has a .db extension and I may not understand the full implications of your quesion, but when I inquired about using subdirectories in the ubiquity container for iCloud storage I was told by someone who I believe was an Apple engineer that subdirectories can be added but that "no directories should have . in their name or they may get treated as a package and that will end sadly for you.  Also you should not put any .nosync entries at the top level of the container."  He also said "Settings will show the Documents as a flat hiearchy (e.g. it'll only show files and packages, not directories) and other UI areas may also visually ignore subdirectories."

In order to have a detail table of files in a subdirectory selected from a master table of directories I resorted to a method for iterating through all the items from a query and finding only the ones which had the subdirectory in the URL.